# SQL Where clause order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    Runs.runID, Runs.runDateTime,
    COUNT(Files.destFileID) AS FileCount
FROM
    Runs
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Files ON Files.runID = Runs.runID
WHERE 
    FileCount > 0
GROUP BY 
    Runs.runID, Runs.runDateTime
ORDER BY 
    Runs.runDateTime
```

It runs fine and displays the expected result without the `WHERE` line, but I do need to filter the resultant data as that would imply.

The error I'm getting is

> Invalid Column Name 'FileCount'

after the `WHERE` keyword.

I've been reading around and I can't find any resources online that include all of the elements I have.

Comment: This was the top result [from a Google search](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-filter-records-with-aggregate-function-count/)

Comment: SQL statements aren't interpreted top to bottom. The sequence is FROM, WHERE, GROUP, HAVING, SELECT, ORDER (no exhaustive, e.g. window functions are done between where and group). You cannot use something from later in the sequence in an earlier part of the sequence

Comment: (a HAVING is a WHERE applied to a GROUP BY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference a column by it's alias in the `WHERE`, you would need to repeat the expression in the `WHERE`. As, however, the expression you have is an aggregate, you actually need to put this in the `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT R.runID,
       R.runDateTime,
       COUNT(F.destFileID) AS FileCount
FROM dbo.Runs R
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Files ON F.runID = R.runID
GROUP BY R.runID,
         R.runDateTime
HAVING COUNT(F.destFileID) > 0
ORDER BY R.runDateTime;
```

To elaborate on why you can't reference the column by it's alias in the `WHERE` (or `HAVING` here), this is due to the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement), which shows that the `WHERE` is 4th part processed, and the `HAVING` 7th, however, the `SELECT` is the 8th processed part. As the `SELECT` hasn't been processed when the `WHERE` is processed it would be impossible for something defined in it [the `SELECT`] to be referenced yet. In a programmatical sense, it would be like trying to reference a variable before you define it.

The order of operations, per the documentation is as follows (thought note this isn't always the case, but the documentation linked earlier covers this in further detail):

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Comment: Yeah those docs are broken. It's missing `APPLY`, `OFFSET`, and window functions, and `ON` and `JOIN` are the same thing (unless it's referring to a nested join, which is also missing),

Comment: @Charlieface You can always raise an issue or send a PR for the docs; they are open source. Saying they are "broken" here doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Larnu, I'll accept your answer when the 10 minutes have expired, but after posting my question, I found that I could just subquery the whole thing:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Runs.runID ,Runs.runDateTime ,COUNT(Files.destFileID) AS FileCount
    FROM Runs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Files ON Files.runID = Runs.runID
    WHERE FileCount > 0
    GROUP BY Runs.runID, Runs.runDateTime
    ORDER BY Runs.runDateTime
)
AS results
  WHERE FileCount > 0
  ORDER BY runDateTime
```

This also works. Does anyone know which of these options are best practices, or the performance of each?

Comment: This seems like a new question, based on that at the end you ask which is the better practice or performer. Though you could inspect the query plans and see if they are run differently (I suspect not).

Comment: I was suppose to gv answer, but larnu's answer is faster and efficient manner as per Sql side.. Impact will show while larger data.

Comment: The performance (and query plan) of this will be exactly the same, although I note you can't have `ORDER BY` in a derived table (nor do you need it)

Comment: I'd use a HAVING, because it's neater